# Is the set of rationals between $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ open or closed in $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers

> Consider the set of all rationals, $\mathbb Q$ as a subset of the set of all reals $\mathbb R$. Assign $\mathbb Q$ the subspace topology induced by the standard topology on $\mathbb R$.
>
> Consider now the set $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ subset of $\mathbb Q$. Is the set open in $\mathbb Q$? Is the set closed in $\mathbb Q$ ? Prove your answer?

#### Solution

This is what I have thought till now:
To prove $X = (\sqrt{ 2}, \sqrt{3})$ is open. Let $p$ belong to $X$.
To prove: $p$ is an interior point of $X$ i.e. there exists a epsilon neighborhood of $p$ which lies in $X$.
I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: If $p$ belongs to $X$, then by definition of $X$, that means that $\sqrt2\lt p\lt\sqrt3$. So $p-\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3-p$ are positive numbers. Let $\epsilon$ be the smaller of those two positive numbers. If you can prove that the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $p$ lies in $X$, then you have proved that $p$ is an interior point of $X$, completing your proof that $X$ is an open set. That answers the first question. Your second question asks if $X$ is a closed set. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: for that second part I have proved that the complement of X is open (similar to how you proved X is open) and hence X is closed. Please correct me if this is not the right approach.

Comment: Yes, the set is both open and closed. One way to prove that $X$ is closed is by proving that the complement is open. Or, if you already know that the intersection of $\mathbb Q$ with a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb Q$, they you can simply observe that $X$ is the intersection of $\mathbb Q$ with the real closed interval $[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]$, since of course $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ are irrational numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Note that in ${\bf Q}$, $V\cap {\bf Q}$ is open when $V$ is open in ${\bf R}$.

So let $V=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. So $V\cap {\bf Q}$ is open in ${\bf Q}$

Comment: That is the answer to the first question. What about the second question, is the set closed in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: $U=\{ x\in {\bf R}|\ x <\sqrt{2}$ or $x>\sqrt{3}\}$ is open so that $W:=U\cap{\bf Q}$ is open. So ${\bf Q}-W$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

This set is open in relation to $\mathbb{Q}$. Remember that a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ iff there is an open set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap B$. Given that every open interval is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$, $(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ is open, which means that $(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q} \cap (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q} \cap [\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}].$ The first expression tells us that it is open and the second expression tells us that it is closed. So it is **both** open and closed.